# How to receive messages from a usb device

Tags: java, android, usb, external

I have a usb device connected to Android that when I press a button(located on the usb device) It sends a 'S' string. How can I detect such string?

When I connect the Usb device to windows, and open any text editor such notepad++ and press the button the 'S' string appears.

I have managed to connect with the device which is a camera and open it. But is there any way to detect when the button is pressed by receaving the string 'S'.

Comment: Verify that the device (Keyboard - USB HID) is able to enumerates and communicate with Android.

Comment: I think there is not magic here... you need to implement the piece of code to receive data from usb device :)

Comment: @Hector I don't want to just read the data from the USB device. I want to receive a message from it when the button is pressed. So, bulkTransfer doesn't work. I tried already. The Usb Device just send the String when button pressed.

Answer (score 0):

From documentation: [USB Host](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html)

USB SERVICE contains a Service to isolate all Usb operations. It's a sample code to read from serial port:

```
String YOUR_DEVICE_NAME;
byte[] DATA;
int TIMEOUT;

USBManager manager = getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
Map<String, USBDevice> devices = manager.getDeviceList();
USBDevice mDevice = devices.get(YOUR_DEVICE_NAME);
USBDeviceConnection connection = manager.openDevice(mDevice);
USBEndpoint endpoint = device.getInterface(0).getEndpoint(0);

connection.claimInterface(device.getInterface(0), true);
connection.bulkTransfer(endpoint, DATA, DATA.length, TIMEOUT);
```

Hope it helps.